# Spaces turning into question marks when scraping using requests html

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

i'm working on a scraper which uses the requests_html module. I made a program which is supposed to get a few usernames from my site however it returns the spaces as question marks.

Here's my code:

```py
self.session = AsyncHTMLSession()
self.users= []

resp = await self.session.get(self.overall)

for a in resp.html.find('a'):
    if "user" in str(a):
        user_array = str(a).split("=")
        username = account_array[2].replace("'>", "")
        self.users.append(username)

print(self.users)
```

Comment: When I see a question mark in *something* coming from an HTML page, I see it as a hint that the original character was not was it pretented to be. Most common example is probably RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`’` or U+2019) instead of APOSTROPHE (`'` or U+0027), but you could have a NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0) instead of a true space (U+0020). If you have a charset problem (Latin1 decoded as if it were UTF-8) you get the question mark for non displayable character. Only a comment because I can be sure where it is relevant for your question...

Comment: How would you suggest me to make it display the space? I'm trying to write it to a file atm and when there's supposed to be a space, it instead is a diamond shape with a question mark inside/Unicode \ufffd

Comment: U+FFFD is the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. I am now pretty sure that your file or byte string contains a 0xa0 byte. Still not an answer because I cannot guess where it comes from exactly. But again I would assume that you are processing a Latin1 byte string as UTF8.

Comment: What does one of these links look like?  When you do `find('a')` and then `str(a)`, that string is the string representation of an `Element` object, e.g. `"<Element 'a' href='#content' title='Skip to content'>"`.  So the string parsing you're doing on that is likely VERY fragile and not what you want.  If the specific links you're looking for are somewhere specific in the page you can use, for example, an *XPath* selector to narrow it down.  Where are you expecting to find the string `"user"`? In the text of the element (`a.text`)? Or in an attribute (`a.attrs`)?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by replacing the unicode character with a space.

```
if u"\uFFFD" in username:
    username = username.replace(u"\uFFFD", " ")
    print(username)
```

Comment: If you would like to answer my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358433/spaces-turning-into-question-marks-when-scraping-using-requests-html#comment104912259_59358433) perhaps I could offer an overall better solution to your problem.  The code you have now is not a very effective approach even if it happens to "work" :)

Comment: Thanks anyways sir, though efficiency is not my concern atm.

Comment: It's not just about efficiency, but also correctness and simplicty.  What you've written is very likely to break and can be greatly simplified.  I'm trying to save you trouble down the road.  It's just not exactly clear what you're trying to do.  But suit yourself.

Comment: Sure, what do you need for this to work properly without it being a cheap hack.

Comment: For example, what does on of your `str(a)` strings look like?  If you're not sure, add `print(repr(str(a)))` to your code.

Comment: ```repr(str(a))``` returns this: "<Element 'a' href='hiscorepersonal?user1=JohnLen'>"

Comment: Yeah, as I thought that's the string representation of the `Element` object, but that object represents a data structure you can access directly; you should not try to "parse" the string representation of the `Element` object itself.  Instead, see that `a.attrs['href']` contains the *value* of the `href` attribute.  You can parse it like: `from urllib.parse import splitquery, parse_qs; parse_qs(splitquery(a.attrs['href'])[1])`, which returns `{'user1': ['JohnLen']}`.